# How to avoid parallel processing of duplicate item in async system in java

Tags: java, multithreading, asynchronous, threadpool, executorservice

I have N threads working on M number of messageIds.
I want if two thread works on same messageId then make them process in synchronize way.
Below is how code is spawning thread in  Async way.

```
@Async("TaskExecutor")
public void process(int messageId) {
   //process messageId
}

@Bean
@Qualifier("TaskExecutor")
public ThreadPoolTaskExecutor poolExecutor() {
    ThreadPoolTaskExecutor poolExecutor = new ThreadPoolTaskExecutor();
    poolExecutor.setCorePoolSize(16);
    return poolExecutor;
}
```

Comment: What do you exactly mean by "I want if two thread works on same messageId then make them process in synchronize way." one after the other? Or do you mean one works with the messageID the other does not?

Comment: What do you mean by "process in a synchronous way"?  Do you actually mean serially; i.e. one after another?   Do you mean ... just once?  Please explain clearly what you mean ...

Comment: For what it is worth, your code does not do what you says it does.  It just creates an `Executor`.  There is no "spawning of threads in an async way" there.  And there certainly isn't any example of getting the threads to actually doing something ... asynchronously.

Comment: @dreamcrash yes when one is working with the messageId i want other to wait until that finishes when the messageId they are working is same. when messageIds are diffrent they can work parallely.